# DOCUSIGN embedded sigging LocalStorgae

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, local-storage, docusignapi

I am using docusign embedded signing feature in my angular app. I am displaying the docusign feature in the `iframe` when the call back from docusign is entertained in my ng-app my `localstorage` data gets messed up. Sometimes the local storage gets duplicate entries of same data or sometimes it changes my localstorage data. There are senarios where everything goes all good. My `localstorage` contains user data so its crucial for me to maintain local storage.

**ADDITION**
When the call back is received ng-app gets loaded into the `iframe` and then the respective controller hides the iframe and continues with the flow. Loading the app again in my iframe is what I think making the problem on the first hand. Just for information docusign also pushes data to localstorage. I think I need to find a way to not to load the app in the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you check [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/), it explicitly mentions that `Please redirect the client to the URL. iFrames should not be used`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but I need it in iframe.

Comment: I don't think DocuSign can help you in your issue, as DocuSign will not change their code to fix the calling app's localstorage issue, you might need to see a solution on your end.